# How to enable local file system read write access from Google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I need to enable local file system read/write access from Google-Chrome using HTML/Javascript code.
I am using set of html pages which are stored in local system (ie file://c:/project1/page.html ...).

My current observation is that we can do local file reading operation using FileReader javascript class without making any extra configuration or settings in the browser.  But when I tried to write in the local file using some JS code it keeps asking for permission by showing Alert box to the User for every write operation.

So my question is, **Is there any way to disable this kind of prompting for file write operation from google-chrome?**
I've seen that chrome stores browser configuration in **master_preferences** file and **Preferences** files located inside chrome installation folder, But couldn't find such kind of entry/record for the same.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Are you writing an extension/app?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs thanks for your reply, Actually i've certain kind of Html/JS reports for that i need this thing. so this is not like any plugin or extension, its just a simple html pages stored locally.

Comment: If you were writing an extension you could request additional permissions when your app/extension is installed.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [JQuery.twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html) for this purpose. It's great for both reading from local flesystem AND writing to it.

It will not show you any errors or prompts when reading or writing a file.

It may show some other kind of prompts though in Chrome. (Java related prompts)

While using it, in order to prevent Java related prompts I launch Chrome in this manner:

C:\Users\WHATEVER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-outdated-plugins --allow-file-access-from-files

ALSO, be sure to do the following:

Go to URL: chrome://plugins/
Then, under Java, be sure checkbox for "Always Allowed" is checked

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Actually it wouldn't be useful for my case as It's dependent on Java & I cant use this in document.ready() call (as its limitation of this jquery plugin).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly are you using to write the file read by ReadFile back out to another file?

Comment: Actually things is I've certain kind of report in html pages which contains some JS functions to manipulate over the html DOM, And those JS functions also reads/writes the the dom manipulation results whenever required. I hope I answered your query.

Comment: hmm indeed, interesting -- because generally it is NOT ALLOWED to write to a file from browser (browser doesn't allow it) - that's why I'm very curious how you manage to do it without any Java or ActiveX plugin -- even with an alert box! In your JS functions, what is name of function which causes an actual file to be written to your local filesystem? What is name of the JS library?